# submitting 2 forms together, passing primary key from one as foreign key in other

Tags: python, django, forms, null, foreign-keys

I have created a form using python and django from 2 seperate modelForms in the one html template. Models:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Action name", max_length=50)
    keywords = models.CharField("Keywords", max_length=50)
    object = models.CharField("Object", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    uploadDate = models.DateField("Date", default=get_current_date)
    UploadedBy = models.CharField("UploadedBy", max_length=50, default="")

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, default="") 
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(datetime.now().day).replace('.','_'), filename)
```

forms:

```
class ActionForm(ModelForm):
    #bind form to Action model
    class Meta:
        model = Action
        fields = ['name','keywords', 'object', 'UploadedBy', 'uploadDate']

class ImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Image
        fields =['image']
```

The code which creates the form in views:

```
def actioncreate(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        #create the object - Actionform 
        form = ActionForm;
        form2 = ImageForm;
        #pass into it 
        return render(request,'app/createForm.html', { 'form':form, 'form2':form2})
    elif request.method == "POST":
        # take all of the user data entered to create a new action instance in the table
        form = ActionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form2 = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if  form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            act = form.save(commit=False)
            img = form2.save(commit=False)
            #set the action_id Foreignkey 
            act.id = img.action_id                 
            act.save()
            img.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/actions')
        else:
            form = ActionForm()
            form2 = ImageForm;
            return render(request,'app/createForm.html', { 'form':form, 'form2':form2 })
```

The form is created fine but when it is submitted, it trys to save image.id, image.image (filename) and returns null for image.action_id
I am getting the error:

```
null value in column "action_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, uploaded_files/29_personrunning_Hq8IAQi.jpg, null).
```

I obviously need to populate the third column with the action.id which django creates itself on submitting the first part 'form'. Is there a way I can get the action.id value and populate the action_id field in the image table in the one form submission?
image.action_id is declared initially as a foreignKey related to action in models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is related to `act = form.save(commit=False)` because it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database, then `act` doesn't have an ID. You need to save (and commit) `act` first.

Also there is another error in following line:

```
act.id = img.action_id  # It should be: img.action_id = act.id
```

You may want to assign `act` to `img.action`. Please note that you are doing it in the wrong way (you are assigning in `img.action` to `act`). The best way to do it is:

```
img.action = act  # This is equivalent to img.action_id = act.id
```

Try swapping these lines:

```
        act.save()
        img.action = act
```